# scp using a different shell?

Tags: scp, tcsh

I have a server where the default shell is tcsh. It has been setup in its .cshrc to load a number of modules on login. So it is quite slow to login and I just have to live with it.

My problem is that these modules are loaded even for an scp connection. Hence becomes frustrating if I have to wait almost a minute for every scp transfer.

I was wondering if there was a way to either disable calling .cshrc during scp transfers or make scp use a different login shell?

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: You can establish and reuse ssh connections, this works also for `scp`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410252/how-to-reuse-an-ssh-connection or https://puppet.com/blog/speed-up-ssh-by-reusing-connections

Comment: You can check for the `SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable in your `.cshrc`.

Comment: Or you can check in `.cshrc` for the variable `loginsh`. This is set only for interactive shells in `tcsh`. For `csh` you would check for the variable `prompt`.

Comment: If it's only for scp multiple times, you can use sftp.

Comment: @mosvy, the SSH_CONNECTION was a good workaround. Thanks! I will see if there are better alternatives suggested, but you should add this as an "answer".